# Is Wordpress a good option for this...?

Tags: theme-development

I want to create two new sites. One will be a simple site with a few pages -- not really a blog, but I might add a blog to it at some point. The other site will be more like a blog -- with guest posts by a number of people, and it will probably have affiliate links -- possibly Amazon links. It might also have Google Ads, display ads.

For both of these sites, I might want to add things, take things away, change things,  etc -- I don't know exactly what I will want to do yet -- I want to have plenty of flexibility here.

And I would like a quick way to make the sites look good visually.

Is Wordpress a good option for these sites?

(I have a dedicated server which is currently running a site in php (which I will keep as-is) and if I understand correctly, to use Wordpress, I'd add the domains for these 2 new sites to the server, download the Wordpress installation files from wordpress.org and then upload those files to my server.)

So I want to check if Wordpress is a good option for these two sites and for what I want to accomplish...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WordPress can do anything you mentioned.

However your question is bit too generic to be sure about anything.

Answer (score 1):

"For both of these sites, I might want to add things, take things away, change things, etc"

Seems like you need a general CMS (Content Management System). From what I can tell, Wordpress would be a very good choice, it's by far the best CMS usability wise.

"And I would like a quick way to make the sites look good visually."

Wordpresses theming system is a very intuitive and easy way to change the visual properties of your site.

Having a pretty good sense of the Content Management Systems out there I'd say that - Yes, Wordpress is a perfect match.